# Does using a virtual environment influence the performance of a web app?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I have a django app up and running. I never encountered any performance problems, though the app is hosted on a shared hosting platform.

The provider asked my recently to use python's `virtualenv`. Since then the performance has been really bad, though I can't detect the change in CPU usage or any other statistic.

So my question is: does using a virtual environment influence the performance? If yes, how?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nope, it doesnt infuence the performance. Basically all what it do is changing python path to the virtualenvs ones. So there shouldn`t be any difference with performance.

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks.