# Integrating Python Poetry with Docker

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, python-poetry

Can you give me an example of a `Dockerfile` in which I can install all the packages I need from `poetry.lock` and `pyproject.toml` into my image/container from Docker?

Comment: There is a really good discussion thread on GitHub. Here is a link to my method: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/discussions/1879?sort=new#discussioncomment-2469844

Comment: In addition to the other great answers here, be sure to check out ["CI recommendations" in the Poetry documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#ci-recommendations).

Answer (score 449):

There are several things to keep in mind when using `poetry` together with `docker`.

### Installation

Official way to install `poetry` is via:

```
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
```

This way allows `poetry` and its dependencies to be isolated from your dependencies.

You can also use `pip install 'poetry==$POETRY_VERSION'`. But, this will install `poetry` and its dependencies into your main `site-packages/`. It might not be ideal.

Also, pin this version in your `pyproject.toml` as well:

```
[build-system]
# Should be the same as `$POETRY_VERSION`:
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.6"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

It will protect you from version mismatch between your local and `docker` environments.

### Caching dependencies

We want to cache our requirements and only reinstall them when `pyproject.toml` or `poetry.lock` files change. Otherwise builds will be slow. To achieve working cache layer we should put:

```
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml /code/
```

After the `poetry` is installed, but before any other files are added.

### Virtualenv

The next thing to keep in mind is `virtualenv` creation. We do not need it in `docker`. It is already isolated. So, we use `POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=false` or `poetry config virtualenvs.create false` setting to turn it off.

### Development vs Production

If you use the same `Dockerfile` for both development and production as I do, you will need to install different sets of dependencies based on some environment variable:

```
poetry install $(test "$YOUR_ENV" == production && echo "--only=main")
```

This way `$YOUR_ENV` will control which dependencies set will be installed: all (default) or production only with `--only=main` flag.

You may also want to add some more options for better experience:

1. `--no-interaction` not to ask any interactive questions
2. `--no-ansi` flag to make your output more log friendly

### Result

You will end up with something similar to:

```
FROM python:3.11.5-slim-bookworm

ARG YOUR_ENV

ENV YOUR_ENV=${YOUR_ENV} \
  PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 \
  PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
  PYTHONHASHSEED=random \
  PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
  PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
  PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
  # Poetry's configuration:
  POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
  POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=false \
  POETRY_CACHE_DIR='/var/cache/pypoetry' \
  POETRY_HOME='/usr/local'
  POETRY_VERSION=1.7.1
  # ^^^
  # Make sure to update it!

# System deps:
RUN curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -

# Copy only requirements to cache them in docker layer
WORKDIR /code
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml /code/

# Project initialization:
RUN poetry install $(test "$YOUR_ENV" == production && echo "--only=main") --no-interaction --no-ansi

# Creating folders, and files for a project:
COPY . /code
```

You can find a fully working real-life example here: [wemake-django-template](https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-django-template/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_name%7D%7D/docker/django/Dockerfile)

### Update on 2019-12-17

- Update `poetry` to 1.0

### Update on 2022-11-24

- Update `curl` command to use modern poetry installation script

### Update on 2024-01-24

- Use `curl` by default to install, not `pip`
- Update to use latest CLI flags

Comment: Readers of this answer may [care to learn about Docker multi-stage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds). I know in my case multi-stage builds greatly simplified the process of base vs test vs app docker images. [See also this post](https://www.lutro.me/posts/python-docker-multi-stage-builds) which is not poetry-specific but shows a reason one _might_ consider continuing to use virtualenv within docker, when doing multi-stage builds. (Not yet tested myself, I've only adopted `poetry` recently.)

Comment: @hangtwenty are you interested in contributing multi-stage builds to wemake-django-template? It would be an awesome feature that will reduce the final image size. If so, drop me a line on github by creating a new issue, please.

Comment: Great idea! [Opened the issue](https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-django-template/issues/697). I'm swamped but I'll look for some time to contribute that soon

Comment: @sobolevn the only worry with `pip install poetry` is that Poetry's dependencies might conflict with app dependencies.

Comment: Actually poetry vendorizes packages which aren't python-only which unfortunately makes their curl installation method unreliable.  I would install via pip until that's fixed

Comment: `poetry config virtualenvs.create false` doesn't work in 1.0.0. Use `RUN POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE=false poetry install` instead.

Comment: It does still work for me: https://travis-ci.com/wemake-services/wemake-django-template/jobs/268486889#L600 Source: https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-django-template/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_name%7D%7D/docker/django/Dockerfile#L58

Comment: In order to easily copy multi-stage build artifacts from one stage to the next, I rely on the `--user` arg to `pip` so that I can simply copy `/root/.local` to my final stage. How would I go about this with poetry?

Comment: If you need to _pin_ the poetry version in `[build-system]`, shouldn't you use `poetry==1.0` instead of using a `>=`?

Comment: Actually, installing poetry with `pip install` *do* conflict with app dependencies as poetry dependencies also have their own dependencies. It is absolutely under control of developer. Using this method it is always recommended to use `pip install --ignore-installed`. I don't like piping something from Internet right in the shell, too. Not to mention that it requires curl, wget or anything else. But, if you decided to do so, there is `--version` option of `get-poetry.py` script.

Comment: This method fell on its own face for me: in my project's `pyproject.toml`, I had everything set up normally. However, `pip install poetry` (on Python 3.7) installs `appdirs` as a dependency of `poetry`, as intended. But when running with `config virtualenvs.create false`, `poetry` runs "bare-metal", and *removes* `appdirs` again (`Removing appdirs (1.4.4)`, while installing normal project dependencies fine). This is because `appdirs` was not listed in `pyproject.toml` (because why would it?). I reverted to using virtual envs again, so that `poetry` doesn't remove `appdirs`.

Comment: @AlexPovel then check out this method: https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-django-template/blob/master/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_name%7D%7D/docker/django/Dockerfile#L55-L58

Comment: As @AlexPovel mentioned, currently there's an [issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/3139) that is caused mainly because the dependencies are not separated. If you use `dephell` or `black` and you have them in `pyproject.toml` in the `dev-dependencies` section stuff blows up if you install with `--no-dev`.  One of the (hopefully temporary) solutions is to install poetry the "official" way.

Comment: Is this essential to COPY `pyproject.toml` together with `poetry.lock`? `pyproject.toml` also contains some linters configuration, for example, and changes in this section trigger unnecessary cache miss. So, is it OK to COPY `poetry.lock` only?

Comment: As a beginner of Poetry: How do I get to such a `pyproject.toml` at the start if not by just entering some dummies first as I suggested at [Poetry could not find a pyproject.toml file in C:\](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68995947/11154841)? Is this totally wrong? Where can I get a "typical" small scale `pyproject.toml` that I can reuse?

Comment: @questionto42 you can run `poetry init`: https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#init

Comment: @sobolevn Yes I meant that. You enter `poetry init` and then you have to fill in some dummies which is confusing at first since you might think you have to add the needed packages instead. I just want to have a standard toml file with dummy values in advance where I just change the Python version to the needed one.

Comment: To avoid dependency conflicts with `poetry` itself, you could also consider installing `poetry` via `pipx` which isolates `poetry` into its own virtualenv: https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installing-with-pipx

Comment: poetry==1.4.1 uses poetry-core = "1.5.2". So `# Should be the same as \`$POETRY_VERSION\`:` is not correct

Comment: To install a specific version of poetry using the official way `curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - --version 1.2.0`

Comment: `--no-dev` is deprecated. Now use `--only main`

Comment: Installing via `curl` is now deprecated, and for the life of me I can't get `pipx` to work on Ubuntu docker images.

Comment: @rjurney, no `curl` installation is not deprecated. `curl .../.../install-poetry.py` installer was deprecated and remove a long time ago. See https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installing-with-the-official-installer

Comment: @sobolevn I see, well that host is blocked by my VPN and I can't get a pipx install to work on Ubuntu Docker. It is quite a challenge.

Comment: I got a pipx install to work. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/78118424/13969

Comment: @sobolevn ok, maybe not deprecated but often problematic from an IT security perspective.

Comment: Hi @sobolevn
I tried to use you `dockerfile` with this call `docker build --build-arg YOUR_ENV=production . -t poetry_production_ifelse --no-cache` but I got the following error: `0.391 /bin/sh: 1: test: production: unexpected operator
0.391 /bin/sh: 1: poetry: not found`

Answer (score 185):

**Multi-stage Docker build with Poetry and venv**

*Update (2024-03-16)*

This has become much easier over the past years. These days I'd use Poetry's bundle plugin to install the application into a virtual environment, then copy the virtual environment into a distroless image. Install Poetry with pipx, which is packaged by Debian. (You likely want to pin Poetry to avoid breakage when your project isn't compatible with a new Poetry release.) Use the option `--only=main` when bundling to omit development dependencies.

```
FROM debian:12-slim AS builder
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install --no-install-suggests --no-install-recommends --yes pipx
ENV PATH="/root/.local/bin:${PATH}"
RUN pipx install poetry
RUN pipx inject poetry poetry-plugin-bundle
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN poetry bundle venv --python=/usr/bin/python3 --only=main /venv

FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian12
COPY --from=builder /venv /venv
ENTRYPOINT ["/venv/bin/my-awesome-app"]
```

*Original Answer*

Do not disable virtualenv creation. [Virtualenvs serve a purpose in Docker builds](https://pmac.io/2019/02/multi-stage-dockerfile-and-python-virtualenv/), because they provide an elegant way to leverage multi-stage builds. In a nutshell, your build stage installs everything into the virtualenv, and the final stage just copies the virtualenv over into a small image.

Use `poetry export` and install your pinned requirements first, before copying your code. This will allow you to use the Docker build cache, and never reinstall dependencies just because you changed a line in your code.

Do not use `poetry install` to install your code, because it will perform an editable install. Instead, use `poetry build` to build a wheel, and then pip-install that into your virtualenv. (Thanks to [PEP 517](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/), this whole process could also be performed with a simple `pip install .`, but due to [build isolation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0517/#id17) you would end up installing another copy of Poetry.)

Here's an example Dockerfile installing a Flask app into an Alpine image, with a dependency on Postgres. This example uses an entrypoint script to activate the virtualenv. But generally, you should be fine without an entrypoint script because you can simply reference the Python binary at `/venv/bin/python` in your `CMD` instruction.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.7.6-alpine3.11 as base

ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 \
    PYTHONHASHSEED=random \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

FROM base as builder

ENV PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1 \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=1 \
    POETRY_VERSION=1.0.5

RUN apk add --no-cache gcc libffi-dev musl-dev postgresql-dev
RUN pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION"
RUN python -m venv /venv

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./
RUN poetry export -f requirements.txt | /venv/bin/pip install -r /dev/stdin

COPY . .
RUN poetry build && /venv/bin/pip install dist/*.whl

FROM base as final

RUN apk add --no-cache libffi libpq
COPY --from=builder /venv /venv
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh wsgi.py ./
CMD ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

. /venv/bin/activate

while ! flask db upgrade
do
     echo "Retry..."
     sleep 1
done

exec gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000 --forwarded-allow-ips='*' wsgi:app
```

**wsgi.py**

```
import your_app

app = your_app.create_app()
```

Comment: @stderr An editable install doesn’t actually install your package into the virtual environment. It creates a .egg-link file that links to your source code, and this link would only be valid for the duration of the build stage.

Comment: Update: Poetry 1.0.0 was released. Pre-release no longer needed to export requirements.

Comment: Also check out Itamar Turner-Trauring's excellent Docker packaging guide for Python: https://pythonspeed.com/docker/. Following his advice, this answer should probably be updated to use a slim Debian image instead of Alpine.

Comment: "Do not use poetry install to install your code, because it will perform an editable install." You can disable this behaviour with [`--no-root`](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#options_1) flag. See a closed Github issue [here](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/800).

Comment: You can use `poetry install --no-root` instead of exporting requirements for `pip install`. But it doesn't help with the editable installs. That [issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1382) is still open

Comment: That's all well and good, except there are times where `poetry export -f requirements.txt` generates invalid requirements files: the same entries are duplicated. This seems to be related to attempting to support different versions of Python.

Comment: Instead of using virtualenv, you can use user install (`--user`) and then just copy whole `$HOME/.local/` into, e. g. `/usr/bin/local/`. There is also `--root` and `--prefix` pip options, but it seems that `--root` is just not working (pip 20.2), and `--prefix` is vague and it is not clear what it actually do. And, as I said, there is no reason to use them as `--user` works perfiect.

Comment: Also, to me, the ideal case could be to do some "pre-processing" before doing docker build, e. g. exporting `requirements.txt` using locally installed poetry. In such case, we could even drop poetry installation from our Dockerfile, which is cool. Unfortunately, this can't be done using docker itself. Definitely, it could be automated using, e. g. shell script, Makefile or something similar. To me, though, such approach seems very inconsistent with whole build process.

Comment: submitted a revision to replace the `requirements.txt` generation step and this one should still maintain the non-editable state

Comment: @Jeffrey04 Can you please submit your version as a separate answer? In the future, I would prefer it if you could first reach out with a comment instead of going ahead and making substantial changes to somebody else's answer.

Comment: sorry, feel free to revert to the original revision

Comment: Note that you don't _have_ to use a venv for a multi-stage build. You can also set a prefix for pip to install into via the `PIP_PREFIX` environment variable. In the base stage, disable virtualenvs, set the prefix to a new directory (e.g. `/install`, mkdir it first!), and in the final stage copy the prefix directory to the Python prefix (could be `/usr`, could be `/usr/local`, could be something else). Assuming the official Python docker images and `/install` as the prefix, you'd use `COPY --from=base /install /usr/local`.

Comment: You don't have to use `. /venv/bin/activate`, it is sufficient in the Dockerfile to use `ENV PATH="/venv/bin:${PATH}"` and `ENV VIRTUAL_ENV="/venv"` which means you can have an inline entrypoint/cmd and it will still use the venv.

Answer (score 44):

This is a minor revision to the [answer provided by @Claudio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57886655/5742), which uses the new `poetry install --no-root` feature as described by [@sobolevn in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54763270/5742).

In order to force [poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) to install dependencies into a specific virtualenv, one needs to first enable it.

```
. /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate && poetry install
```

Therefore adding these into @Claudio's answer we have

```
FROM python:3.10-slim as base

ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 \
    PYTHONHASHSEED=random \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

FROM base as builder

ENV PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1 \
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=1 \
    POETRY_VERSION=1.3.1

RUN pip install "poetry==$POETRY_VERSION"

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock README.md ./
# if your project is stored in src, uncomment line below
# COPY src ./src
# or this if your file is stored in $PROJECT_NAME, assuming `myproject`
# COPY myproject ./myproject
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true && \
    poetry install --only=main --no-root && \
    poetry build

FROM base as final

COPY --from=builder /app/.venv ./.venv
COPY --from=builder /app/dist .
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh .

RUN ./.venv/bin/pip install *.whl
CMD ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

If you need to use this for development purpose, you add or remove the `--no-dev` by replacing this line

```
RUN . /venv/bin/activate && poetry install --no-dev --no-root
```

to something like this as shown in @sobolevn's answer

```
RUN . /venv/bin/activate && poetry install --no-root $(test "$YOUR_ENV" == production && echo "--no-dev")
```

after adding the appropriate environment variable declaration.

The example uses debian-slim's as base, however, adapting this to alpine-based image should be a trivial task.

Comment: So I really like this answer, but how would I deal with local path dependencies?

Comment: what do you mean by local path dependencies?

Comment: Path dependencies are useful in monorepo setups, where you have shared libs somewhere else in your repo, see [the docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#path-dependencies)

Comment: add the respective `COPY` commands before the `RUN poetry install` or `RUN poetry build` I suppose? my answer (as well as the referenced ones) practically just replicate the setup in the container, just that we explicitly set the venv to be `/venv/`, if the setup in the container is identical to your work setup everything technically should run fine, just think how you would replicate the setup elsewhere without docker and adjust the Dockerfile accordingly?

Comment: @Jeffrey04 `COPY` the local package in doesn't work for me.

I get `pip._vendor.pkg_resources.RequirementParseError: Invalid URL: my-package` during the command `RUN . /venv/bin/activate && pip install *.whl`

Comment: have you checked if the file layout is identical inside the container?

Comment: If you copy the venv and run from venv what is the reason you also copy the dist and pip install the wheel? @Jeffrey04

Comment: hmm, i probably need to revise this, but not currently working with docker much in my current job (i stopped tinkering with it after i got it working back then). If you have time to fix and test feel free to edit my answer (:

Comment: I guess the point of copying venv over is to prevent installing the dependencies multiple times

Comment: I don't understand the added benefit in this answer. You are now installing twice, one time in the builder image, and again in the final image.

Answer (score 30):

## TL;DR

I have been able to set up `poetry` for a `Django` project using `postgres`. After doing some research, I ended up with the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:slim

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install and setup poetry
RUN pip install -U pip \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt install -y curl netcat \
    && curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python -
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.poetry/bin"

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
  && poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

This is the content of `entrypoint.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$DATABASE" = "postgres" ]
then
    echo "Waiting for postgres..."

    while ! nc -z $SQL_HOST $SQL_PORT; do
      sleep 0.1
    done

    echo "PostgreSQL started"
fi

python manage.py migrate

exec "$@"
```

## Detailed Explanation

Some points to notice:

- I have decide to use `slim` instead of `alpine` as tag for the `python` image because even though `alpine` images are supposed to reduce the size of Docker images and speed up the build, with Python, you can actually end up with a bit larger image and that takes a while to build (read [this article](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/) for more info).
- Using this configuration builds containers faster than using the alpine image because I do not need to add some extra packages to install Python packages properly.
- I am installing `poetry` directly from the URL provided in the documentation. I am aware of the warnings provided by `sobolevn`. However, I consider that it is better in the long term to use the lates version of `poetry` by default than relying on an environment variable that I should update periodically.
- Updating the environment variable `PATH` is crucial. Otherwise, you will get an error saying that *poetry was not found*.
- Dependencies are installed directly in the python interpreter of the container. It does not create `poetry` to create a virtual environment before installing the dependencies.

In case you need the `alpine` version of this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:alpine

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install dev dependencies
RUN apk update \
    && apk add curl postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev openssl-dev libffi-dev

# Install poetry
RUN pip install -U pip \
    && curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python -
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.poetry/bin"

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . .
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
  && poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi

# run entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Notice that the `alpine` version needs some dependencies `postgresql-dev gcc python3-dev musl-dev openssl-dev libffi-dev` to work properly.

Comment: _consider that it is better in the long term to use the lates version of poetry_ - No, really isn't. Because a major breaking change in some new release of Poetry can break your entire build, so you'd have to modify it to use a hard-coded release version anyway

Comment: I use `curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python - --version 1.1.13` to specify a version and not break the build

Comment: How can i make this work with a **non-root** user on docker? I'm getting `poetry not found` when tried as non root user.

Comment: This solution has the disadvantage that the dependency layer has to be rebuilt every time you change your app code. It is better to switch the COPY and RUN statement and use `--no-root`. Using this option, poetry will only install dependencies and will not install your app, which is not needed in this context.

Answer (score 21):

That's minimal configuration that works for me:

```
FROM python:3.7

ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on

RUN pip install poetry

WORKDIR /app
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml /app/

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false
RUN poetry install --no-interaction

COPY . /app
```

Note that it is not as safe as [@sobolevn's configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54763270/1161025).

As a trivia I'll add that [if editable installs will be possible for `pyproject.toml` projects](https://github.com/sdispater/poetry/issues/34), a  line or two could be deleted:

```
FROM python:3.7

ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on

WORKDIR /app
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml /app/

RUN pip install -e .

COPY . /app
```

Comment: If case your project also contains a Python module `mymodule` that you would like to be installed -- as Poetry does by default if it finds one -- you need create a dummy version like so before running poetry install: `RUN mkdir /app/mymodule && touch /app/mymodule/__init__.py`. This works because Poetry installs these type of modules using pip -e, which just creates a symbolic link. This means thing work as expected when the real modules is copied over it in the final step. (According to mods this is a commment and not an edit -- please try incorporate it into the post if you disagree.)

Comment: Running pip install poetry doesn't create a poetry lock or pyproject for my project. It's only after you use poetry does the file get create so I have no idea why this would work.

Comment: @AlxVallejo It's a snippet for Poetry-based applications, which use to have both lock and pyproject file. `poetry new` or `poetry init` can help you kickstart new app.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a stripped example where first a layer with the dependencies (that is only build when these changed) and then one with the full source code is added to an image. Setting `poetry` to install into the global `site-packages` leaves a configuration artifact that could also be removed.

```
FROM python:alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip \
 && pip install --no-cache-dir poetry \
 \
 && poetry config settings.virtualenvs.create false \
 && poetry install --no-dev \
 \
 && pip uninstall --yes poetry \

COPY . ./
```

Answer (score 15):

Use docker multiple stage build and python slim image, export poetry lock to requirements.txt, then install via pip inside virtualenv.

It has **smallest size**, **not require poetry** in runtime image, pin the versions of everything.

```
FROM python:3.9.7 as base
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1
WORKDIR /app

FROM base as poetry
RUN pip install poetry==1.1.12
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml /app/
RUN poetry export -o requirements.txt

FROM base as build
COPY --from=poetry /app/requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN python -m venv .venv && \
    .venv/bin/pip install 'wheel==0.36.2' && \
    .venv/bin/pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

FROM python:3.9.7-slim as runtime
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH=/app/.venv/bin:$PATH
COPY --from=build /app/.venv /app/.venv
COPY . /app
```

Comment: I used the following to let poetry create the venv directly:

`FROM base as poetry
RUN pip install poetry==1.1.13
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.in-project true
COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock /app/
RUN poetry install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-root`

Answer (score 13):

My Dockerfile based on [@lmiguelvargasf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53835198/integrating-python-poetry-with-docker/61751745#61751745). Do refer to his post for a more detailed explanation. The only significant changes I have are the following:

- I am now using the latest official installer `install-poetry.py` instead of the deprecated `get-poetry.py` as [recommended in their official documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/#installing-with-the-official-installer). I'm also installing a specific version using the `--version` flag but you can alternatively use the environment variable `POETRY_VERSION`. More info on their official docs!
- The `PATH` I use is `/root/.local/bin:$PATH` instead of `${PATH}:/root/.poetry/bin` from OP's Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10.4-slim-buster

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install curl -y \
    && curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python - --version 1.1.13

ENV PATH="/root/.local/bin:$PATH"

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
    && poetry install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-ansi

COPY ./src ./

EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "poetry", "run", "gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:5000", "test_poetry.app:create_app()" ]
```

Comment: Their [main page]((https://python-poetry.org/docs/)) still is recommending the github URL that everyone else has mentioned. Using the installer mentioned here does not read `POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_CREATE` environmental variable, not sure if it has a bug with ENVs or not.

Comment: "The PATH I use is /root/.local/bin:$PATH" <-- This is great, but... Could you please explain a reason? Thanks.

Comment: That is not a multistage build and you will have to install the dependencies every time you build the container.

Comment: Bonus points for `poetry run gunicorn` :)

Comment: upvoted! why this line? poetry config virtualenvs.create false what happens if dockerr creates a .venv inside your project?

Comment: What's the idea behind poetry run? I thought it purpose was to run anything in the proper project venv. But with venvs disabled, this doesn't seem useful to me

Answer (score 10):

I've created a solution using a lock package (package which depends on all versions in the lock file). This results in a clean pip-only install without requirements files.

Steps are: build the package, build the lock package, copy both wheels into your container, install both wheels with pip.

Installation is: `poetry add --dev poetry-lock-package`

Steps outside of docker build are:

```
poetry build
poetry run poetry-lock-package --build
```

Then your `Dockerfile` should contain:

```
FROM python:3-slim

COPY dist/*.whl /

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir /*.whl \
    && rm -rf /*.whl

CMD ["python", "-m", "entry_module"]
```

To allow this to work for multiple platforms, the first steps can be done in a first stage of a multistage build. Example:

```
FROM python:alpine AS builder

WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip \
 && pip install --no-cache-dir poetry

COPY . ./

RUN poetry add --group dev poetry-lock-package
RUN poetry build
RUN poetry run poetry-lock-package --build

FROM python:alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/dist/*.whl /

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir /*.whl \
    && rm -rf /*.whl

CMD [ "python", "-m", "entry_module" ]
```

Comment: perfect solution. my original comment about python source code is incorrect, pip would install everything into site-packages.

Comment: It seems if your docker container OS and the host OS are different this would not be a good time

Comment: This is really a great solution to provide a very lightweight Docker image. As @Mattwmaster58 commented, the wheel files should be built in the same context as the final Docker image. Therefore I added an example for a multistage build.

Answer (score 7):

I provide a Poetry docker image to the community. This image is always available for the latest three Poetry versions and different Python versions. You can pick your favorite:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/pfeiffermax/python-poetry

You can check the Docker file for the practices I applied there. It's quite simple: https://github.com/max-pfeiffer/python-poetry/blob/main/build/Dockerfile

```
# References: using official Python images
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
ARG OFFICIAL_PYTHON_IMAGE
FROM ${OFFICIAL_PYTHON_IMAGE}
ARG POETRY_VERSION

LABEL maintainer="Max Pfeiffer <max@maxpfeiffer.ch>"

# References:
# https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/caching/#avoiding-caching
# https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/?highlight=PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR#cmdoption-no-cache-dir
# https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/?highlight=PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK#cmdoption-disable-pip-version-check
# https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip/?highlight=PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT#cmdoption-timeout
# https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/#environment-variables
# https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation

ENV PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
    PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    POETRY_VERSION=${POETRY_VERSION} \
    POETRY_HOME="/opt/poetry"

ENV PATH="$POETRY_HOME/bin:$PATH"

# https://python-poetry.org/docs/#osx--linux--bashonwindows-install-instructions
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
        build-essential \
        curl \
    && curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python - \
    && apt-get purge --auto-remove -y \
      build-essential \
      curl
```

This image I use as base image in two other projects where you can see how to utilise Poetry for creating virtual environments and run Python applications using Uvicorn and/or Gunicorn application servers :

- https://github.com/max-pfeiffer/uvicorn-poetry
- https://github.com/max-pfeiffer/uvicorn-gunicorn-poetry

Dockerfile of first image: https://github.com/max-pfeiffer/uvicorn-poetry/blob/main/build/Dockerfile

```
# The Poetry installation is provided through the base image. Please check the
# base image if you interested in the details.
# Base image: https://hub.docker.com/r/pfeiffermax/python-poetry
# Dockerfile: https://github.com/max-pfeiffer/python-poetry/blob/main/build/Dockerfile
ARG BASE_IMAGE
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE}
ARG APPLICATION_SERVER_PORT

LABEL maintainer="Max Pfeiffer <max@maxpfeiffer.ch>"

    # https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONUNBUFFERED
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    # https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PYTHONPATH=/application_root \
    # https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvsin-project
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true \
    POETRY_CACHE_DIR="/application_root/.cache" \
    VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENT_PATH="/application_root/.venv" \
    APPLICATION_SERVER_PORT=$APPLICATION_SERVER_PORT

# Adding the virtual environment to PATH in order to "activate" it.
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#how-venvs-work
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENVIRONMENT_PATH/bin:$PATH"

# Principle of least privilege: create a new user for running the application
RUN groupadd -g 1001 python_application && \
    useradd -r -u 1001 -g python_application python_application

# Set the WORKDIR to the application root.
# https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/#development
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#workdir
WORKDIR ${PYTHONPATH}
RUN chown python_application:python_application ${PYTHONPATH}

# Create cache directory and set permissions because user 1001 has no home
# and poetry cache directory.
# https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#cache-directory
RUN mkdir ${POETRY_CACHE_DIR} && chown python_application:python_application ${POETRY_CACHE_DIR}

# Document the exposed port
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#expose
EXPOSE ${APPLICATION_SERVER_PORT}

# Use the unpriveledged user to run the application
USER 1001

# Run the uvicorn application server.
CMD exec uvicorn --workers 1 --host 0.0.0.0 --port $APPLICATION_SERVER_PORT app.main:app
```

If you structured it like this the Dockerfile of a sample application can be as simple as this doing a multistage build: https://github.com/max-pfeiffer/uvicorn-poetry/blob/main/examples/fast_api_multistage_build/Dockerfile

```
# Be aware that you need to specify these arguments before the first FROM
# see: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact
ARG BASE_IMAGE=pfeiffermax/uvicorn-poetry:3.0.0-python3.10.9-slim-bullseye@sha256:cdd772b5e6e3f2feb8d38f3ca7af9b955c886a86a4aecec99bc43897edd8bcbe
FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} as dependencies-build-stage

# install [tool.poetry.dependencies]
# this will install virtual environment into /.venv because of POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true
# see: https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvsin-project
COPY ./poetry.lock ./pyproject.toml /application_root/
RUN poetry install --no-interaction --no-root --without dev

FROM ${BASE_IMAGE} as production-image

# Copy virtual environment
COPY --chown=python_application:python_application --from=dependencies-build-stage /application_root/.venv /application_root/.venv

# Copy application files
COPY --chown=python_application:python_application /app /application_root/app/
```

Answer (score 6):

I see all the answers here are using the pip way to install Poetry to avoid version issue.
The official way to install poetry read POETRY_VERSION env variable if defined to install the most appropriate version.

There is an issue in github [here](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/discussions/1879#discussioncomment-216865) and I think the solution from this ticket is quite interesting:

```
# `python-base` sets up all our shared environment variables
FROM python:3.8.1-slim as python-base

    # python
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    # prevents python creating .pyc files
    PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    \
    # pip
    PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on \
    PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    \
    # poetry
    # https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#using-environment-variables
    POETRY_VERSION=1.0.3 \
    # make poetry install to this location
    POETRY_HOME="/opt/poetry" \
    # make poetry create the virtual environment in the project's root
    # it gets named `.venv`
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=true \
    # do not ask any interactive question
    POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1 \
    \
    # paths
    # this is where our requirements + virtual environment will live
    PYSETUP_PATH="/opt/pysetup" \
    VENV_PATH="/opt/pysetup/.venv"


# prepend poetry and venv to path
ENV PATH="$POETRY_HOME/bin:$VENV_PATH/bin:$PATH"


# `builder-base` stage is used to build deps + create our virtual environment
FROM python-base as builder-base
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
        # deps for installing poetry
        curl \
        # deps for building python deps
        build-essential

# install poetry - respects $POETRY_VERSION & $POETRY_HOME
RUN curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sdispater/poetry/master/get-poetry.py | python

# copy project requirement files here to ensure they will be cached.
WORKDIR $PYSETUP_PATH
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./

# install runtime deps - uses $POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT internally
RUN poetry install --no-dev


# `development` image is used during development / testing
FROM python-base as development
ENV FASTAPI_ENV=development
WORKDIR $PYSETUP_PATH

# copy in our built poetry + venv
COPY --from=builder-base $POETRY_HOME $POETRY_HOME
COPY --from=builder-base $PYSETUP_PATH $PYSETUP_PATH

# quicker install as runtime deps are already installed
RUN poetry install

# will become mountpoint of our code
WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["uvicorn", "--reload", "main:app"]


# `production` image used for runtime
FROM python-base as production
ENV FASTAPI_ENV=production
COPY --from=builder-base $PYSETUP_PATH $PYSETUP_PATH
COPY ./app /app/
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["gunicorn", "-k", "uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker", "main:app"]
```

Comment: You shouldn't really need a venv while running code in a container

Comment: @OneCricketeer Poetry is not designed to work without a venv. It literally uses venvs to do dependency management. That said, another reason why people may want venvs is if they are using distroless containers. The way it's done is via multi-stage builds and moving the venv (which only has the required python dependencies for the given app) to a dedicated container without the clutter of an entire os. Many Flask apps are done like this. Unless, of course, you like containers that are gigs in size - making them  not very portable. Container size isn't just about security and attack surface.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a different approach that leaves Poetry intact so you can still use `poetry add` etc. This is good if you're using a VS Code devcontainer.

In short, install Poetry, let Poetry create the virtual environment, then enter the virtual environment every time you start a new shell by modifying `.bashrc`.

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip curl

# Use Python 3 for `python`, `pip`
RUN    update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python  python  /usr/bin/python3 1 \
    && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pip     pip     /usr/bin/pip3    1

# Install Poetry
RUN curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-poetry/poetry/master/install-poetry.py | python3 -
ENV PATH "$PATH:/root/.local/bin/"

# Install Poetry packages (maybe remove the poetry.lock line if you don't want/have a lock file)
COPY pyproject.toml ./
COPY poetry.lock ./
RUN poetry install --no-interaction

# Provide a known path for the virtual environment by creating a symlink
RUN ln -s $(poetry env info --path) /var/my-venv

# Clean up project files. You can add them with a Docker mount later.
RUN rm pyproject.toml poetry.lock

# Hide virtual env prompt
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT 1

# Start virtual env when bash starts
RUN echo 'source /var/my-venv/bin/activate' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Reminder that there's no need to avoid the virtualenv. It [doesn't affect performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16871438/16769904) and Poetry isn't really designed to work without them.

EDIT: @Davos points out that this doesn't work unless you already have a `pyproject.toml` and `poetry.lock` file. If you need to handle that case, you might be able to use this workaround which should work whether or not those files exist.

```
COPY pyproject.toml* ./
COPY poetry.lock* ./
RUN poetry init --no-interaction; (exit 0) # Does nothing if pyproject.toml exists
RUN poetry install --no-interaction
```

Comment: Looks clean. You are copying the pyproject.toml and lock file, did you create those manually or do you also use poetry on your host machine to create the project first? If so then why use the remote container with vscode?

Comment: Good point - this doesn't work in a fresh repo. It assumes you've already set up Poetry manually. You could modify that section to copy the files if they're available. I've added a suggestion in the answer above.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers were good but I had to make some modifications based on the following requirements I had:

1. I wanted a small image and so wanted to use Alpine.
2. I wanted to be sure not to run the final image as root.
3. I was particularly focused on being able to run a Poetry script from my `pyproject.toml` by name.

For example, if I have this script in the `pyproject.toml`:

```
...
[tool.poetry.scripts]
my_tool = "my_tool.cli.cli:start"
...
```

Then, I wanted `my_tool` (a CLI) to be my Dockerfile `ENTRYPOINT` so that the arguments provided by the container commands would be arguments to my CLI.  This solution accomplished exactly what I was looking for:

```
# Stage - base
FROM python:3.11-alpine3.18 as base

ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1 \
    PYTHONHASHSEED=random \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

WORKDIR /app

# Stage - builder
FROM python:3.11-alpine3.18 as builder

ENV PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100 \
    PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=1 \
    POETRY_VERSION=1.7.0

RUN pip install poetry==$POETRY_VERSION

WORKDIR /app

RUN python -m venv /venv

COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock ./
RUN . /venv/bin/activate && poetry install --no-dev --no-root

COPY . .
RUN . /venv/bin/activate && poetry build

# Stage - release
FROM base as release

# install sudo as root
RUN apk add --update sudo

# add new user
ENV USER=appuser
RUN adduser -D $USER \
        && echo "$USER ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d/$USER \
        && chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d/$USER

ENV PATH="/venv/bin:$PATH"

COPY --from=builder /venv /venv
COPY --from=builder /app/dist .
RUN chown -hR $USER /venv

RUN . /venv/bin/activate && pip install *.whl

USER $USER

ENTRYPOINT ["my_cli"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile for my python apps looks like this -

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine
RUN apk update && apk upgrade
RUN pip install -U pip poetry==1.1.13
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN poetry export --without-hashes --format=requirements.txt > requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
EXPOSE 8000
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
CMD ["main.py"]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a multi-stage dockerfile that doesn't include poetry at runtime?

Comment: Yes that would work too with slightly increased build time or we can even remove poetry after _RUN poetry export_ line as poetry is only needed to generate the ***requirements.txt*** file.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest removing after RUN, at least not as a new RUN, since that'll add a new layer and increase image size

Comment: Makes sense in that case just may be add `RUN poetry export --without-hashes --format=requirements.txt > requirements.txt && pip uninstall poetry`
Also, I recently faced issues with poetry dependency resolver while working with some ML libraries _(found a video that explains that issue - 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gr9o8MW_pb0)_. Now I'm reconsidering whether poetry is a good choice :/

Answer (score 0):

In some corporate environments, you can't run `curl` to the hostname `install.python-poetry.org` because you use something like Artifactory to install packages from a local repository. Here is a recipe for installing `pipx` to install `poetry`.

These lines in your `Dockerfile` will work if you replace the `${UID}`, `${GID}` and `${USER}` variables with appropriate values.

```
# Install poetry so we can install our package requirements
RUN python3 -m pip install --no-cache-dir --user pipx && \
    python3 -m pipx ensurepath

ENV PATH "/home/jovyan/.local/bin:$PATH"
RUN pipx install poetry==${POETRY_VERSION}

# Copy our poetry configuration files as jovyan user
COPY --chown=${UID}:${GID} pyproject.toml "/home/${USER}/work/"
COPY --chown=${UID}:${GID} poetry.lock    "/home/${USER}/work/"

# Install our package requirements via poetry. No venv. Squash max-workers error. Cleanup afterwards.
WORKDIR "/home/${NB_USER}/work"
RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false && \
    poetry config installer.max-workers 10 && \
    poetry install --no-interaction --no-ansi --no-root -vvv && \
    poetry cache clear pypi --all -n
```