# How to use poetry with docker?

Tags: python, docker, virtualenv, dependency-management, python-poetry

How do I install poetry in my image? (should I use `pip`?)

Which version of poetry should I use?

Do I need a virtual environment?

There are [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53835198/integrating-python-poetry-with-docker) [examples](https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-django-template/blob/8719ccee322436b6af56835bb6e3eb07ce992718/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_name%7D%7D/docker/django/Dockerfile) and [opinions](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1178#issuecomment-517812277) in [the](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/discussions/1879#discussioncomment-216870) [wild](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/poetry-vs-docker-caching/) which offer different solutions.

Comment: For inspiration, [you can find a production example Poetry + Dockerimage here.](https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/trade-executor/blob/master/Dockerfile)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

## TL;DR

Install poetry with pip, configure virtualenv, install dependencies, run your app.

```
FROM python:3.10

# Configure Poetry
ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.2.0
ENV POETRY_HOME=/opt/poetry
ENV POETRY_VENV=/opt/poetry-venv
ENV POETRY_CACHE_DIR=/opt/.cache

# Install poetry separated from system interpreter
RUN python3 -m venv $POETRY_VENV \
    && $POETRY_VENV/bin/pip install -U pip setuptools \
    && $POETRY_VENV/bin/pip install poetry==${POETRY_VERSION}

# Add `poetry` to PATH
ENV PATH="${PATH}:${POETRY_VENV}/bin"

WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./
RUN poetry install

# Run your app
COPY . /app
CMD [ "poetry", "run", "python", "-c", "print('Hello, World!')" ]
```

## In Detail

### Installing Poetry

> How do I install poetry in my image? (should I use `pip`?)

#### Install it with `pip`

You should install poetry with pip. but you need to isolate it from the system interpreter and the project's virtual environment.

> For maximum control in your CI environment, installation with pip is fully supported ... offers the best debugging experience, and leaves you subject to the fewest external tools.

```
ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.2.0
ENV POETRY_VENV=/opt/poetry-venv

# Install poetry separated from system interpreter
RUN python3 -m venv $POETRY_VENV \
    && $POETRY_VENV/bin/pip install -U pip setuptools \
    && $POETRY_VENV/bin/pip install poetry==${POETRY_VERSION}

# Add `poetry` to PATH
ENV PATH="${PATH}:${POETRY_VENV}/bin"
```

### Poetry Version

> Which version of poetry should I use?

Specify the latest stable version explicitly in your installation.

Forgetting to specify `POETRY_VERSION` will result in *undeterministic builds*, as the installer will always install the latest version - which may introduce breaking changes

### Virtual Environment (virtualenv)

> Do I need a virtual environment?

Yes, and you need to configure it a bit.

```
ENV POETRY_CACHE_DIR=/opt/.cache
```

The reasons for this are somewhat off topic:

> By default, poetry creates a virtual environment in $HOME/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs to isolate the system interpreter from your application. This is the desired behavior for most development scenarios. When using a container, the $HOME variable may be changed by [certain runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#home), so creating the virtual environment in an independent directory solves any reproducibility issues that may arise.

### Bringing It All Together

To use poetry in a docker image you need to:

1. [Install](https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/#installation) your desired version of poetry
2. [Configure](https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvsin-project) virtual environment location
3. [Install](https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/cli/#install) your dependencies
4. Use `poetry run python ...` to run your application

### A Working Example:

This is a minimal flask project managed with poetry.

You can copy these contents to your machine to test it out (expect for `poerty.lock`)

#### Project structure

```
python-poetry-docker/
|- Dockerfile
|- app.py
|- pyproject.toml
|- poetry.lock
```

##### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.10 as python-base

# https://python-poetry.org/docs#ci-recommendations
ENV POETRY_VERSION=1.2.0
ENV POETRY_HOME=/opt/poetry
ENV POETRY_VENV=/opt/poetry-venv

# Tell Poetry where to place its cache and virtual environment
ENV POETRY_CACHE_DIR=/opt/.cache

# Create stage for Poetry installation
FROM python-base as poetry-base

# Creating a virtual environment just for poetry and install it with pip
RUN python3 -m venv $POETRY_VENV \
    && $POETRY_VENV/bin/pip install -U pip setuptools \
    && $POETRY_VENV/bin/pip install poetry==${POETRY_VERSION}

# Create a new stage from the base python image
FROM python-base as example-app

# Copy Poetry to app image
COPY --from=poetry-base ${POETRY_VENV} ${POETRY_VENV}

# Add Poetry to PATH
ENV PATH="${PATH}:${POETRY_VENV}/bin"

WORKDIR /app

# Copy Dependencies
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./

# [OPTIONAL] Validate the project is properly configured
RUN poetry check

# Install Dependencies
RUN poetry install --no-interaction --no-cache --without dev

# Copy Application
COPY . /app

# Run Application
EXPOSE 5000
CMD [ "poetry", "run", "python", "-m", "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0" ]
```

##### `app.py`

```py
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, Docker!'
```

##### `pyproject.toml`

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "python-poetry-docker-example"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["Someone <someone@example.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
Flask = "^2.1.2"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

##### `poetry.lock`

```ini
[[package]]
name = "click"
version = "8.1.3"
description = "Composable command line interface toolkit"
category = "main"
optional = false
python-versions = ">=3.7"

[package.dependencies]
... more lines ommitted
```

Full contents in [gist](https://gist.github.com/soof-golan/6ebb97a792ccd87816c0bda1e6e8b8c2).

Comment: This answer turned out to be quite long, edits welcome to reduce mental overhead

Comment: Your answer is very good and will written. I just disagree with the point to disable virtual environments in a docker image. venv's isolate the dependencies of your application from the one installed in the system. And those exists in a docker images the same way as in a "normal" system.

Comment: [off topic] @finswimmer, disabling virtualenv within docker actually solved a reproducibility bug I experienced with Google Cloud Run. 
In my first version, I left poetry with its default config, and it created a virtual environment during the build.
Running locally with `docker run` worked as expected. 
When starting up the **same image** (same sha256) with Cloud Run poetry creates another virtualenv, empty of all dependencies and the app fails to start (due to  a missing pacakage).
This was kind of shocked about docker reproducibility in general, but wanted to post a valid solution.

Comment: [still off topic] Apparently Cloud Run [modify the HOME variable](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/issues#home) (), that is the root cause of my reproducibility issue.

Comment: For the most part, I like this approach; however, I'm curious about installing Poetry via pip rather than the official installer. What are the tradeoffs?

Comment: (My answer is mostly taken from [poetries CI recommendations](https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/#ci-recommendations).)

@KyleAdams , The official installer does a lot of under-the-hood magic to install poetry, that is not desirable in a CI environment and might be harder to debug compared to installing with pip.

You trade-off ease of use (official installer) for fine grained control on what happens inside your container.

A trivial example: the contents of the installer change over time compared installing a pinned version with pip.

Comment: The POETRY_HOME environment variable isn't used. The example code uses POETRY_VENV instead (the poetry CI instructions use POETRY_HOME).

Comment: I am getting 127.0.0.1 refused to connect. Any suggestions?
`This site can’t be reached127.0.0.1 refused to connect.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Answer (score 22):

I prefer to use multistage builds so I can get rid of poetry in my actual release images and keep those images slim.

```
FROM python:3.10-slim AS builder

ENV POETRY_HOME="/opt/poetry" \
    POETRY_VIRTUALENVS_IN_PROJECT=1 \
    POETRY_NO_INTERACTION=1

# to run poetry directly as soon as it's installed
ENV PATH="$POETRY_HOME/bin:$PATH"

# install poetry
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends curl \
    && curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -

WORKDIR /app

# copy only pyproject.toml and poetry.lock file nothing else here
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./

# this will create the folder /app/.venv (might need adjustment depending on which poetry version you are using)
RUN poetry install --no-root --no-ansi --without dev

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

FROM python:3.10-slim

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1 \
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1 \
    PATH="/app/.venv/bin:$PATH"

WORKDIR /app

# copy the venv folder from builder image 
COPY --from=builder /app/.venv ./.venv
```

Comment: This does not seem to work, : Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable?
Also, why did you change the .venv to venv?

Comment: @Rizerzero you are right, I did not meant to rename .venv (typo) and I edited my answer

Comment: if add a command like poetry main.py, the packages installed in the virtualenv are not found

Comment: If we just COPY poetry.lock and pyproject.toml, where does the project specific Python code get copied?  Should there be a "COPY . /app" line somewhere in the last image?

Comment: @MikeDalrymple yes, do a `COPY . .` or something similar and adjust the PYTHONPATH if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I provide a Python Docker Image with Poetry installed which is ready to use as builder base for your own images. Images are available for the last three Poetry and Python versions: https://github.com/max-pfeiffer/python-poetry

I also provide some other images which incorporate the [already mentioned practices (virtual environment, multistage builds)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73324820/17545728). There you can also find some additional examples on how to utilise Poetry and to build images for web applications:

- https://github.com/max-pfeiffer/uvicorn-poetry
- https://github.com/max-pfeiffer/uvicorn-gunicorn-poetry