# Poetry project lock file and Docker container installation

Tags: python, docker, pypi, python-poetry, aws-codeartifact

I have a Python project with Poetry which i would like to upload to CodeArtifact (like any other Python Repository) and then install it into a Docker container. My Python project has dependencies in the `pyproject.toml` like

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
pandas = "^2.1.4"
pytest-mock = "^3.12.0"
```

the `^` means that even higher versions are accepted. But as soon as I have my project working I also have a `poetry.lock` file. This prevents higher versions from being installed with `poetry install`.
Now when everything is working, I run `poetry build` and upload the lib to CodeArtifact.

If I want to install this library into a Docker container, I could run `pip install` and specify the version of my lib.

My questions are now:

- Is this installation going to respect the `poetry.lock` file? Or is it going to install the latest dependencies for example `pandas 2.2.0`
- How can I prevent newer versions? Which is to say: Do I have to remove it from the pyproject.toml file? Or do have to copy the lock file to the container and run `poetry install`?

Comment: "_is this installation going to respect the poetry.lock file?_" No. Poetry's lockfile (`poetry.lock`) is used only by Poetry's command line interface (via `poetry install` for example). The lockfile content is never written to the package metadata, the lockfile itself is never added to the wheel file. -- I recommend experimenting with `poetry export` instead and use it as a contraint file for pip.

Comment: that seems for me the best solution till yet to basically export a requirements.txt from the installed dependencies which should be equal to the lock file. And then publish the package. But then i cant use poetry build, because it will use the toml file or cannot handle the requirements.txt

Comment: Yes, that is one of the drawbacks, you now have to re-export every time there is a change to `poetry.lock`.

Answer (score 1):

If you've run `poetry build` to create a package and uploaded that package to codeartifact, that package is now ready to be installed by a package manager (eg `pip install` or `poetry add`), regardless of whether the "caller" is in a container.

#### Making your container dependencies mirror your local project

If you want to make your dependency versions follow the `poetry.lock` and exactly mirror those in your local project, you can install Poetry in your container, copy in the `poetry.lock` from your local project, and do poetry install in the container.

Here's an example (several, actually) of [how this is done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72465421/how-to-use-poetry-with-docker).

### How dependency resolution works

Dependency management tools like Pip and Poetry will look at the dependencies specified in the `pyproject.toml` of each of the dependencies in your project, compare them with each other, and determine which dependency versions will satisfy the project (and dependency requirements) without causing conflicts.

In your case, this means that the version of Pandas that gets installed will change based on your environment and the other dependencies in the project.

#### A concrete example:

- You're in project Foo. You do `poetry build`, making Foo an installable package
- Foo package has within it a `pyproject.toml`, that specifies its dependency requirements
- A different project: "Bar" now installs Foo via Poetry or Pip (etc). Let's say we did `pip install foo`

The behavior is as follows:

- Pip looks at the pyproject.toml files in each of Bar's dependency packages (and *their* subdependency packages)
- Pip determine what "maximum version" of each subdependency can be installed and still:

  1. Meet all package requirements
  2. Not create conflicts

These dependency managers are "smart" in that they will upgrade dependencies only as high as the dependencies will support.

##### For example:

- You install package `bar` that relies on `mydep = <=2.0.5`
- Now you install package `qux` that relies on `mydep = <=2.1.0`
- Mydep will be installed, but only as far as version 2.0.5.

#### How to prevent higher versions

**IMPORTANT:** Pip and Poetry respect [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/). Semantic versioning highlights breaking changes to libraries (changes in public API, etc), so dependency managers know "just how far they can upgrade" without breaking your code. **It is not recommended to manually edit versions requirements** - this is what dependency managers like Poetry are for!

Now with that caveat, you can use "less than or equals" notation in your requirements files (typically `pyproject.toml`) to "lock" a dependency at a particular version or set a cap. Eg.`mydep = <=2.0.5` will go no higher than 2.0.5 and `mydep = =2.0.5` will be exactly 2.0.5. Then if you have poetry for example, you'd run `poetry update mydep` to lock that change into your `poetry.lock` file.

Comment: i dont get what the use of the lockfile is, if i have a lock file that locked pandas on 2.1.4 and the toml file allows ^2.1.4 , that would mean if 2.2.0 is released everythiing is fine working because we have differen versions in the testing environment but in production higher versions are allowed which could potentially break the application. So isnt there a way to use the lock file to rewrite the toml file ? or use the lock file direclty to build a package?

Comment: @Khan the lock file is mostly for end user who does not publish a package, but builds a system for himself instead. In such case he's improving reliability: versions won't be updated on every build, if lockfile is checked and copied to container using `poetry install`.

Comment: Let's say app "Foo" relies on Pandas. If you are deploying Foo directly, you can add your poetry.lock to the container and use Poetry in the container to install your *exact* deps. That's described above in "mirror your local project". The link shows you how. Now let's say you're deploying app Bar that relies on Foo: Here, you'd typically rely on Semantic Versioning and your tests - minor version changes (eg. 2.0.1 to 2.1.0) should be non-breaking and your code + CI/CD flow should be robust enough to handle them. Our code should handle minor deps changes so (for example) devs can fix bugs.

Comment: i understand your suggestion but this seems not the correct way for me since I have codeartifact which should be the only source for my packages. If I start copying toml and lock files, then my code artifact is useless. 
If I have to copy these files, then I can need codeartifact. I have to clone the files from my repository and then I could call poetry install and the lock file is used. And for the semantic versioning, pandas 2.1.4 was upgraded to 2.2.0 and it has so many bugs, nothing is working for me.

Comment: The suggestions are just best practices. If the Pandas upgrade is breaking your code, you can manually pin or cap Pandas in your `pyproject.toml` like this: `pandas = <="2.1.4"` (or remove the `<=` to pin to a specific version). Then run `poetry update pandas` to update your .lock file. Dependency managers will respect your change going forward. I added a a bit to the last part of the answer to clarify.