# PyCharm: How to install poetry dependencies before debugging a Python app in a container?

Tags: python, docker, debugging, pycharm, python-poetry

I have a Python application that I am developing in PyCharm Professional 2022.1.2 on Windows. I am using Poetry to manage my application and all package dependencies are listed in `pyproject.toml`.

I would like to debug my application in Linux in a Docker container.

I've successfully set up a Remote Docker Interpreter based on [documentation from JetBrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#config-docker) but when I try to run my application with it, I get this error:

```
70a53fea2bae:python -u /opt/project/myapp/cli/main.py serve 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/project/myapp/cli/main.py", line 7, in <module>
    from myapp.dashboard import serve_dashboard
  File "/opt/project/myapp/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from myapp.pipeline.api.data_reader import ExperimentReader
  File "/opt/project/myapp/pipeline/api/data_reader.py", line 7, in <module>
    from pandas import DataFrame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

This makes me think that my application's package dependencies have not been installed inside the container.

How can I get PyCharm to install my dependencies (`poetry install` presumably?) before running my app?

Comment: What does your docker file look like?

Comment: @Jortega I'm not using a `Dockerfile`. I pointed PyCharm to public image: `python:3.9.13-buster`. That only contains Debian Buster + Python.

Comment: So how are you installing the python modules in the docker container then? Create a docker file that points to the image python:3.9.13-buster.

Comment: @Jortega Thanks. I'm trying to avoid having to author a Dockerfile that installs the packages for me. I'm looking for a solution that will install them for me, a bit like how PyCharm makes my code available in the container automatically. Not sure if PyCharm does this or if it's possible TBH.

Comment: Interesting idea... You could push your own docker image to the docker repository.

Answer (score 1):

The image you're using `python:3.9.13-buster` is delivered without your extra dependencies. It is like a raw python installation on your local machine.

If you want to enhance it with your custom dependencies, you need to create a `Dockerfile` which instructs `docker` to build a new image based on `python:3.9.13-buster` but with your extra dependencies (`pandas`) preinstalled.

I'd suggest starting with [this](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) tutorial to get familiar with how docker works and how to define custom images using `Dockerfile` and how to build & use them.

PS Here is some SO answer with example how such `Dockerfile` for image which installs dependencies defined using poetry's `pyproject.toml` may look like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71786211/6082882 but again I'd suggest starting with learning docker fundamentals.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I am quite familiar with how docker works etc. The expectation in my question is that similar to how PyCharm makes y code automatically available to the running container, it (PyCharm) should also make dependencies available there. Should I learn that this is not within PyCharm's current functionality, I will follow up on your suggestion to implement through a Dockerfile myself.