# poetry does not install the package when run in Docker, but all the dependencies is installed

Tags: python, docker, python-poetry

I have a docker-image in which I want to install my own package, `mypackage`, using the `.toml` and `.lock` file from `poetry` - inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53835198/integrating-python-poetry-with-docker) SO answer.

It seems to work fine, all the dependencies in the `.toml` are being installed but the package itself is not.

If I add an `RUN poetry add mypackage` I get an error `Package 'mypackage' is listed as a dependency of itself`. If I don't I get a `ModuleError: No module named 'mypackage'`.
If I spawn er terminal in the container, I can `pip list` the dependencies, but not `mypackage`

I have also tried copying `mypackage/` into my `workdir` (`scripts/`) in the `Dockerfile` but the same issue persists. Maybe there's some file-structure that's wrong? I'm not very experience with Docker, thus some of the files might not be where I think they are.

```
# pyproject.toml

[tool.poetry]
name = "mypackage"
version = "1"
description = ""
authors = ["me"]
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "~3.10"
waitress = "2.1.2"
flask = "2.2.2"
scikit-learn = "1.2.1"
cython = "^0.29.33"
gensim = "^4.3.0"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

and

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-bullseye

RUN apt update && apt install
RUN apt install python3-pip -y

RUN pip install "poetry==1.3.1"

RUN mkdir /scripts

COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml /scripts/
# COPY mypackage/ /scripts/ 
WORKDIR /scripts

RUN poetry config virtualenvs.create false \
  && poetry install --no-dev --no-interaction --no-ansi

# RUN poetry add mypackage

CMD poetry run python -c "import mypackage;"
```

Comment: You do not copy the source code of your package to the docker container, do you? From the dockerfile, it seems that you are only copying the pyproject.toml and poetry.lock file. I.e. the information about the dependencies of your package. Not the package itself.

Comment: I have tried to do it ( the `# COPY mypackage/ /scripts/`) but it does not seem to make any difference (of course after removing the "#")

Comment: AFAIK `COPY mypackage/ ...`will copy the contents of the directory, not the directory itself. Could you verify that the directory layout in the container is as expected? I.e. that directory `mypackage` is not missing.

Comment: Argh, you are 100% correct! What a stupid typo; `COPY mypackage/ /scripts/mypackage ` is the correct command