# How can I properly build a python project with a git submodule inside a Docker container using poetry?

Tags: python, docker, git-submodules, python-poetry

### Background:

I'm trying to build a python project with a git submodule inside a Docker container.
For handling all dependencies I am using poetry version 1.4. My Docker container is based on the python:3.11.3-slim image and
the Dockerfile is mostly the same as the multi stage example from this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57886655).

Simplified file structure (only relevant files):

```
project
│   Dockerfile
│   poetry.lock
│   pyproject.toml
│
└───main module
│   │   cli.py
│   │
│   └───main_module_name
│       │   main_module.py
│
└───submodule
│   │   Dockerfile
│   │   poetry.lock
│   │   pyproject.toml
│   │
│   └───module_name
│       │   cli.py
│       └───subfolder
│           │   submodule.py
```

### Problem:

When I'm importing the submodule on my local development machine I have to specify the full path including the top level folder ('submodule' folder) of the submodule.
But in my Docker container the submodule is installed inside `/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/` without the top level folder, so that the import of the module fails because of the changed folder structure.

I tried to install the `.whl` file of the submodule like [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-t):

```bash
RUN poetry build && /venv/bin/pip install dist/*.whl --target path/to/target
```

but then pip installs the site packages from the `/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/` also in my top level submodule folder. Furthermore I don't want to use an absolute path, so that I can use this project as a template for other project where I might use a different base image.

My current temporary solution copies the sitepackage folder of the submodule after installation with some bash commands:

```bash
RUN export source_path=$(/venv/bin/pip show module-name | grep Location | cut -d ' ' -f2)/module_name/
 && export destination_path=$(/venv/bin/pip show module-name | grep Location | cut -d ' ' -f2)/submodule/
 && mkdir -p $destination_path
 && mv $source_path $destination_path
```

This solution is working, but I think there should be a proper way to install the submodule correctly from the start.

Do you know why the folderstructure is off? 
Do you know a better way to fix this problem?