# I cannot host Django app with docker-compose, and boilerplates request

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker

I wish some guidelines, or maybe a tutorial, to develop a good Django app based on examples, its models and practices. At some point, I stumble on some in complexity exponential increment due many Django features.

So far, I have been able to construct this app: https://github.com/trouchet/tarzan. I even wrote a [Medium blog post](https://medium.com/p/174e7cd08f36) based on ChatGPT. However, there is complexity on the way.

**Example**: Command run `docker compose up` with `docker-compose.yaml` content as below and Dockerfile as on repository exits the container with logs as follows:

- How to reproduce:

  1. Open terminal;
  2. Run command `docker-compose up`;
  3. Run command `docker ps -a`;
  4. Run command `docker ps -a --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}" | grep "tarzan-box" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker logs`;
- `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  # Your Django application
  web:
    image: tarzan-image:latest
    container_name: tarzan-box
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
  
  db:
    image: postgres:13
    container_name: tarzan-memory
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
```

- Dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

# Set environment variables for Python (recommended)
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Create and set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install system dependencies (if needed)
RUN pip install poetry Django

# Copy only the pyproject.toml and poetry.lock files to leverage Docker cache
COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock manage.py /app/

# Install project dependencies
RUN poetry install

# Copy the rest of the application code into the container
COPY src/ /app/src/

# Expose the port on which your Django app will run (e.g., 8000)
EXPOSE 8000

# Start the Django development server
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

- Logs of command rn `docker ps -a --format "table {{.ID}}\t{{.Names}}" | grep "tarzan-box" | awk '{print $1}' | xargs docker logs`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 5, in <module>
    import django
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 5, in <module>
    import django
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Comment: If you're trying to learn a new language or framework, I'd suggest not trying to also learn Docker at the same time.  MacOS and Linux systems come with Python preinstalled and you can set up Django in a virtual environment.  Programs that use their language's native packaging system well tend to be easy to translate into containers.  If you want more help debugging this particular issue, some key details like the `Dockerfile` are missing, and you'll need to [edit] the question to include those.

Comment: Hi, sir David. I made as you requested, added Dockerfile content and a way to get logs from respective exited container.

Comment: Poetry normally installs into a dedicated virtual environment; do you need to [disable that](https://python-poetry.org/docs/faq/#i-dont-want-poetry-to-manage-my-virtual-environments-can-i-disable-it) in your Docker setup ("activating" a virtual environment in a container is tricky)?  This detail among others is mentioned in [Integrating Python Poetry with Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53835198/integrating-python-poetry-with-docker).

Comment: First of all, thanks for showing me the post. It made me aware of environment set to false. However, is still something missing: although the database last word is "accepting connections", it keeps saying `connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Cannot assign requested address`. I thought, it would be because I did not run the migrations still that moment, but require the script run `./docker-utils.sh`... May you please use your 29 gold medals to help a noob?

Comment: `localhost` in Docker usually means "the current container"; you need a different host name to connect to the database, usually its Compose service name `db`.

Comment: This solved my issue like a charm! Thanks for the help, @DavidMaze. Do mind writing this comment or another version as an answer? Thanks.